# Overwriting ng-Bootstrap styling

Tags: css, sass, popover, ng-bootstrap

I am new to css so still trying to figure this out but I have a pop-over I am trying to style. The component is provided by ng-bootstrap and has general sass styling for the theme of the application. Right now I am trying to change the width of the pop-over however I can't seem to increase it beyond a set width (about 276px).

To clarify, I've tried changing the style of the classes of the pop-over in my container but that only applies to the contents of the pop-over supplied by the container itself not the body of the pop-over, so the contents width increases and they overflow but the pop-over itself stays the same size.

I've tried editing scss files supplied for the theme which work on the body of the container but the width doesn't increase so I believe there's a max-width applied by ng-bootstrap that I can't seem to overwrite. I would like to know how I can overwrite the styling in my local scss file.

Below is the code for the global pop-over theme and my current code for my local container.
Global Theme: PopOver.scss

```
.popover {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    .arrow {
        margin-left: -7px !important;
    }
    .popover-header {
        padding: 1rem 0.75rem 0.5rem;
        display: block;
        background-color: $secondary;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
    }
    .popover-body {
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        color: $body-color;
    }
    .popover-close {
        position: absolute;
        top: -2px;
        right: 0;
        padding: 0 0.5rem;
        color: $gray-lighter;
        font-size: 2rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
        &:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            color: $body-color;
        }
    }
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        li {
            margin: 0 -1rem;
            padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        }
        li:hover {
            background: $table-accent-bg;
            cursor: pointer;
            & a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: $body-color;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

local Style Sheet: team-container.component.scss

```
.team-container {

    .icon {
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      display: inline-block
    }

    .icon.icon-team {
      background-position: -5px -5px;
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px
    }
}
```

The location of the files if it's important at all:

-Lib/Themes (Global Theme Styles)

-Src/app/containers/team (target popOver is located here)

I FIGURED IT OUT! unfortunately only by changing the global css class .popover
how can I overwrite .popover in my local css file? 
I've tried .popover .team-container and it didn't work.

Comment: have you tried adding `!important` to your css rule to overwrite Bootstrap's css?

Comment: yes, it didn't work unfortunately =/

Comment: I figured out how to change width by adjusting max-width with !important in the global file. However, I don't know how to overwrite .popover (the global style) in my local file